# pywinauto find_elements() returns ElementNotFoundError

Tags: python, pywinauto

I'm trying to automate a simple app using pywinauto & Python 3.6. The app has a Windows "Open" dialog like this and I want to click on the "Cancel" button:
[image]

I used SWAPY to get the class_name and control_id attributes for the button.
[image]

Now the problem is that when I call the find_element() method with these parameters it raises an ElementNotFoundError. Here's my code:

```
cancel_button = pywinauto.findwindows.find_element(class_name="button", control_id=2)
```

I've tried `(class_name="button", control_id="2")`, `(class_name="Button", control_id=2)` but they all give the same error. The same problem occurs for any other element I try to find on this dialog.

So how do I use the attributes read from SWAPY? I didn't find the official pywinauto documentation to be very useful. It doesn't explain a lot of things clearly.

**EDIT:** I decided not to use the find_elements method and instead used find_windows() to get a handle to the Open dialog.

```
w_open_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Open', class_name='#32770')[0]
```

I then get a WindowSpecification object using this handle:

```
w_open = app.window_(handle=w_open_handle)
```

I then call:

```
w_open['Cancel'].click()
```

and this works. Now I want to enter a file name in the "File name:" edit box and click on Open button to open that file. So I do this:

```
w_open['File name:'].type_keys("abc.txt")
```

This works. I printed out the control identifiers using print_control_identifiers() and got the name for Open button. So using draw_outline() I draw a boundary outside it and it shows the correct button.

```
w_open['SplitButton6'].draw_outline()
```

But calling .click() method on 'SplitButton6' throws a **WindowSpecification class has no 'click' method** error. Any idea what's causing this? The error seems to be misleading since WindowSpec class does have a .click method.

Comment: The [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) should explain a lot.

Comment: As I said, the official guide doesn't explain these things.

Comment: But it explains higher level things you should use to achieve better productivity. See my answer for more details.

Comment: Proof link that `top_level_only` is described in the docs: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.findwindows.html#pywinauto.findwindows.find_elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct answer is that you missed `top_level_only=False` (it's `True` by default because higher level API calls it at least twice). Then you may have 2 controls matching this criterion (maybe from different applications). `find_element` is a low level function. I wouldn't recommend its direct usage (the code is too long, there are many pitfalls that were taken into account on a higher level API).

```
>>> pywinauto.findwindows.find_element(class_name="Button", control_id=2, top_level_only=False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "...\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 98, in find_element
    raise exception
ElementAmbiguousError: There are 2 elements that match the criteria {'class_name': 'Button', 'control_id': 2, 'top_level_only': False}

>>> pywinauto.findwindows.find_element(class_name="Button", title='Cancel', top_level_only=False)
<win32_element_info.HwndElementInfo - 'Cancel', Button, 395554>
```

Using higher level API (`Application` object and `WindowSpecification`s described in the Guide) you shouldn't care about passing process id, backend name and other things to `find_element` every time.

P.S. In my mind SWAPY could be significantly improved, but it's not maintained last year. I hope to re-write it in the future with smaller code base and MS UI Automation support. But currently fully automatic script generator is a higher priority.

---

EDIT:

This button `w_open['SplitButton6'].draw_outline()` could be detected as general `HwndWrapper` object instead of `ButtonWrapper`. You can check it using this:

```
w_open['SplitButton6'].wrapper_object()
```

And this is what exactly written in the Getting Started Guide (which you said you've read).

Fortunately you can use method `.click_input()` for any control:

```
w_open['SplitButton6'].click_input()
```

I can say more: WindowSpecification does NOT have `click` method. It's a method of `ButtonWrapper` which is instantiated dynamically. For example these statements work the same way (but Python can hide `.wrapper_object()` call):

```
w_open['SplitButton6'].wrapper_object().click_input()
w_open['SplitButton6'].click_input()
```

And again this is all described in the [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). Please read the whole guide. You will find many useful high level things. I can advise for some corner cases if something is still not clear.

Comment: I tried setting top_level_only=False & I still get ElementNotFoundError!

Comment: Which statement do you run?

Comment: pywinauto.findwindows.find_element(class_name="Button", control_id=2, top_level_only=False)

Comment: I decided to not use the find_element method. Instead I'm using find_windows to get a handle to the Open dialog.

Comment: `find_windows` is just a wrapper around `find_elements` we made for backward compatibility. Why not just `app.OpenDialog.CancelButton.click()`? Or `app.OpenDialog.child_window(class_name='Button', control_id=2).click()`?

Comment: Vasily, I've edited the question with some more info. Could you please guide me based on the new info?

Comment: Thank you Vasily. using the .click_input() method worked i.e. the button was clicked, but the console shows some error:

 ','.join([str(coord) for coord in coords]) + ')'

TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Comment: Can you submit a separate question with more detailed description? I need full traceback. You may file an issue on GitHub also.

Comment: while my code worked on one machine, it does not work on another machine. Do the control identifiers vary from machine to machine?

Comment: Sometimes it's possible, but it might be a timing problem if slower machine takes more than default 5 seconds to init some controls or to open some windows.

Comment: Actually what I've seen is that the specific window opens up just fine, but the click occurs on a wrong element. The said click is the last one in the sequence so its highly likely because of a wrong identifier. What would be the best way to fix this?

Comment: Probably you need to rely on more stable properties like using `title/title_re`, `class_name/control_type` or other text props. Control ID is not guaranteed to be always unique and the same on every platform (it's often assigned dynamically). So I'd recommend never use `control_id` in your window specifications.